# Modular exponentiation with large numbers

Tags: racket

The following code is slow:

```
(define base 2945795152904547855448158643091235482997756069461486099501216307557115896772)
(define prime 115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494337)

(modulo (expt base (- prime 2)) prime)
```

Is there any way to do this faster?

For example, Python has a [`pow`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow) built-in function that can compute this quickly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rosetta Code has [a Racket implementation](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Racket).

It uses `modular-expt` from `math`.

[Documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/math/number-theory.html#%28def._%28%28lib._math%2Fnumber-theory..rkt%29._modular-expt%29%29)

Examples:

```
> (modulo (expt -6 523) 19)
13
> (modular-expt -6 523 19)
13
> (modular-expt 9 158235208 19)
4
```